What is the "measure-theoretic product"?
From reading categories of measure theory in nLab and its reference written by D. Pavlov, I learned that the category of compact strict localizable enhanced measurable spaces (CSLEMS) is complete and its product is "the measure-theoretic product", which corresponds to the coproduct in the category of commutative von Neumann algebras. However, I don't know how to define products in CSLEMS. I am not familiar to von Neumann algebras.
I conjecture that the product of $X$ and $Y$ in CSLEMS is defiend as: Decompose $X$ to $(X_{\alpha})$ so that each $X_{\alpha}$ adimits a finite measure $\mu_{\alpha}$ using the strict localizability of $X$. Decompose $Y$ to $(Y_{\beta})$ and take $\nu_{\beta}$ in the same way. $X\times Y$ can be decomposed to $(X_{\alpha}\times Y_{\beta})$. Define the negligible sets of $X_{\alpha}\times Y_{\beta}$ by the $\mu_{\alpha}\otimes\nu_{\beta}$-null sets, which is independent from the choice of $\mu_{\alpha}$ and $\nu_{\beta}$.

I couldn't prove my conjecture. Is it correct?
If this is the correct definition, how does compactness work? It seems that only strict localizability is used.

Thanks.
